# Linear algebra. Show all real values of $t$ such that ${(t,1,0);(1,t,1);(0,1,t)}$ is linearly dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

So, as expected, I wrote those vectors as the matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}1&t&1\\ \:t&1&0\\ \:0&1&t\end{pmatrix}

Which can be simplified to:
$$\begin{pmatrix}t&1&0\\ 1&t&1\\ 0&1&t\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}t&1&0\\ 0&\frac{t^2-1}{t}&1\\ 0&1&t\end{pmatrix} \sim \begin{pmatrix}t&1&0\\ 0&\frac{t^2-1}{t}&1\\ 0&0&\frac{t^3-2t}{t^2-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

To my understanding, to obtain the values of $t$ I should see from which values the rows are all zero. So first I should solve the equation $\frac{t^3-2t}{t^2-1} = 0$. That result in $t \neq \pm 1$ $t = 0$ or $t = \pm \sqrt2$. But now I need to check all the other rows, so I divide $\frac{t^3-2t}{t^2-1}$ by $\frac{t^2-1}{t^3-2t}$, and subtract it from the second row, leading to

\begin{pmatrix}t&1&0\\ 0&\frac{t^2-1}{t}&0\\ 0&0& 1\end{pmatrix}

Solving the equation I end up with: $t \neq 0$ and $t = \pm1$. Repeating the same process as above:

\begin{pmatrix}t&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0& 1\end{pmatrix}

Which gives me $t=0$.

Everything appeared to be good and clear, but when I decided to test those values in the actual vectores, it only yield true to $ \pm \sqrt{2} $ and $0$. So why was $\pm 1$ discarded? If it was from the existence condition of $\frac{t^3-2t}{t^2-1}$ why wasn't $0$ discarded? Was my method correct at all?

For some context, this exercise was given as a complement to chapter 12 of Apostol's Calulus 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you have complicated the problem I don't know. It is very easy calculation according to me. You have to show the vectors $(t,1,0), (1,t,1), (0,1,t)$ are linearly dependent,i.e., the equation:
$a(t,1,0)+b(1,t,1)+c(0,1,t)=0$ is true for some non-zero $a,b,c$.
i.e., the equations:
$at+b=0, a+bt+c=0, b+ct=0$ has non-zero solution. So
$det\begin{pmatrix}t&1&0\\ \:1&t&1\\ \:0&1&t\end{pmatrix}=t(t^2-1)+1(0-t)=0\implies t=0,\pm \sqrt{2}$

Comment: Although it is an easy calculation it is important to rephrase that this exercise was given as a complement to chapter 12 of Apostol's Calulus 1, in which it was not proven or shown that we can prove linearly dependency by the determinant. We only had the concepts of linear dependency, linear combination and bases.

Comment: Here I haven't use the determinant to prove linear dependency. I here use the determinant as a condition for non-zero solution of homogeneous system of equations.

Comment: Oh, now I see it... Didn't thought about that. thank you for the cleaver and simple answer.